# React native paper button background color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, material-design, expo

I have this button from https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/button.html

```
<Button onPress={goSignUp}>
    Sign Up
</Button>
```

It hasn't got a background color (just what I want), but when I press it, a background color with a ripple fades in. How do I remove the onPress background color?

Answer (score 2):

Please use `TouchableOpacity`

if you used `TouchableHighlight`
Try to add this

```
 <TouchableHighlight underlayColor='none' />
```

Comment: The question is about the Button component that is been used from the library mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You may ask, why don't you use a touchable opacity instead of the button? The answer is that I have more buttons (with background color) and I want to have all buttons with the same default style which comes with react-native-paper.

I have found a solution (wrap the button inside the TouchableOpacity) but I think there has to be a better way...

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={goSignUp}>
   <Button style={styles.button}>Sign Up</Button>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 1):

This library has a prop for buttons called mode, you can try pass mode props to it, or just use your custom style

```
<Button mode='contained'>Sign Up</Button>
```

or

```
<Button style={{width: 200, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>Sign Up</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
         <Button 
            mode="contained"
            buttonColor='#001871'
            onPress={() => console.log('Button Pressed')}>SAVE
          </Button>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can give styles as same as react native default. as an example-

```
<Button style={{backgroundColor: 'orange'}} icon="account-plus-outline" mode="contained-tonal" onPress={() => console.log('Pressed')}>
            Register me! </Button>
```